# Не могу вывести рекурсию по фигуре

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, фракталы

Задача: Изобразить следующий фрактал

[image: Фрактал]

Насколько я понял, суть заключается в пятиугольниках. Создаётся пятиугольник, затем его более увеличенная версия, внутри которой находится 5 штук более мелких и т.д. А звезда формируется само собой.

Допустим создать пятиугольник, или же 5 пятиугольников вокруг 1 точки - не проблема, но как это сделать рекурсией, да ещё и как на рисунке - ума не приложу

Comment: _«Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос»_. Если трудности с реализацией рекурсии, то вопрос следует дополнить кодом, при написании которого они возникли.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предположу что:

1. На первой итерации рисуется отрезок и пятиугольник лежащий одним ребром на нем по центру одно ребро пятиугольника равно трети исходного отрезка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. На второй итерации 7 отрезков полученных в пункте 1 подвергается процедуре в описанной пункте 1, тут важен порядок обхода.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3. повторяем процедуру рекурсивно сколько нужно раз
4. Profit

[интересная ссылка](https://elementy.ru/posters/fractals/Sierpinski)

P.S: вот результат четырех итераций предложенного мной алгоритма

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот и сам алгоритм, я его расширил чтобы можно было рисовать родственные фракталы

```html
<input id="shape" type="range" min="3" max="9" value="5" onchange="draw()">
<input id="iterarions" type="range" min="1" max="5" value="3" onchange="draw()">
<span></span><br>
<canvas width=1000 height=600 style="height:80vh"></canvas>
<script>
let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
draw();

function draw() {
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
    let t = new Date().getTime();
    let lines = fractal([[[10, 599], [980, 599]]], 0);
    lines.forEach(l => drawLine(l[0], l[1]))
    t = new Date().getTime() - t;
    document.querySelector('span')
        .textContent = ' segments: '+lines.length+', time ' + t +' ms';
}

function fractal(bases, i) {
    if (i === +document.querySelector('#iterarions').value) 
        return bases;
    let n = +document.querySelector('#shape').value;
    let cs = Math.cos((180*(n-2))*Math.PI/180/n);
    let sn = Math.sin((180*(n-2))*Math.PI/180/n);
    let result = [];
    bases.forEach(base => {
        let x0 = base[0][0], y0 = base[0][1];
        let x1 = base[1][0], y1 = base[1][1];
        let dx3 = x1/3-x0/3, dy3 = y1/3-y0/3;
        let sublines = [];
        sublines.push([[x0, y0], [x0+dx3, y0+dy3]]);
        sublines.push([[x0+dx3, y0+dy3], [x0+dx3*2, y0+dy3*2]]);
        for (var i=0; i<n-1; i++)
            sublines.push(nextEdge(...sublines[sublines.length-1]));
        sublines.push([[x0+dx3*2, y0+dy3*2], [x1, y1]]);
        result = result.concat(sublines);
    })
    return fractal(result,i+1);
    
    function nextEdge(p1, p2) {
        let x = p1[0]-p2[0];
        let y = p1[1]-p2[1];
        let px = x * cs - y * sn; 
        let py = x * sn + y * cs;
        return [[p2[0],p2[1]], [p2[0]+px, p2[1]+py]];
    }
}

function drawLine(p1, p2){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(p1[0], p1[1]);
    ctx.lineTo(p2[0], p2[1]);
    ctx.stroke();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Имхо https://i.imgur.com/ywHVX0l.jpg

Comment: @yar85 с точностью до перекладинки снизу, и на Вашей картинки сразу по 2 итерации

Comment: Перекладинка незначительный нюанс (особенно при большой глубине рекурсии), суть в том что такой паттерн ближе к фрактальной кривой, как мне кажется. Про итерации согласен, просто я в мобильном скетчбуке рисовал, и терпения не хватило бы на детальный степ-бай-степ :]

Comment: @yar85 да это похоже на звезду Коха

Comment: @yar85 и все таки мне кажется что на картинке только лишь третья итерация, а в пределе похоже что перекладинка появится и с Вашим алгоритмом

Comment: Отсчет итераций зависит от общего алгоритма. Я представляю примерно так, как показано на картинке, то есть три вызова общей функции отрисовки (2 из них рекурсивно), с последовательным обходом ребер. Так получится результат как на картинке в вопросе. Разница с твоим вариантом только в том, что кол-во ребер (и длина цикла) втрое больше, до 15ти, так как +2 боковых пятиугольника. Почему _до_ - предполагается что короткие ребра не будут добавляться в массив "задания" на следующий рекурсивный вызов, тем самым естественно ограничивая "степень" фрактала (хз как это правильно называется).

Comment: @yar85 я чувствую надо будет запилить

Comment: То есть, представляю "задание" рекурсивной функции как массив отрезков, на которых будет отрисована эта фрактальная кривая. Каждое следующее задание заполняется прямо в процессе отрисовки, на нужных `lineTo` (мы ведь знаем на каких линиях будут созданы ребра пятиугольников, а на каких не будут), просто пушим если длина >= минимальной. И, так как у нас есть это ограничение минимальной длины ребра, объем данных задания не будет особо большим - поэтому, оптимизировать их не вижу смысла. **p.s.:** Сорри за долгий набор текста))